# 3Box returns error rather than desired account info

Tags: solidity, external-api, typescript

3box returns

```
{"status":"error","message":"Address link not found, address does not have a 3Box or is malformed"}
```

when using

```
 this.profile = this.threebox.getProfile(this.direction).then((response) => {//error thrown here, 404
        console.log(response);
        this.profile = response;
        this.url = this.profile.image[0].contentUrl["/"];
      });
```

the website also returns this if you look on api it connects to

https://ipfs.3box.io/profile?address=0x3b2ffeef1c81649c3be919dca6f3f9b70f9f6e8e

anyone know why 3box doesnt return the desired output?

is 3box deprecated and not used anymore?

Comment: Did you try asking their customer support? It doesn't seem to be an Ethereum related issue.

Comment: I have solved this, it seems 3Box has migrated into a new platform called SelfID and IMX so they dont update users anymore